# NSIS: how to check for Windows Desktop App version for core NET 6?

Tags: registry, .net-6.0, nsis

I have the need to check for the existence of NET 6 installed on the server when we deploy our apps.  When trying to check for the Windows Desktop App binaries I see in the registry there are multiple values:

[image]

I would like to check to see if at least a version of NET 6 exists:

```
StrCpy $0 0
loopx86:
ClearErrors
EnumRegValue $1 HKLM SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\sharedfx\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App $0
IfErrors errorx86
IntOp $0 $0 + 1
ReadRegStr $2 HKLM SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\sharedfx\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App $1
StrCmp $1 "6.0.9" donex86 loopx86
errorx86:  
 MessageBox MB_OK "x86 Windows Desktop App not found?!"  
 Abort
donex86:
 MessageBox MB_OK "x86 Loop done?!"
```

This works if I specify the exact version info... however I just want to check if 6.x exists for Windows Desktop App... without having to depend on a full version check.  I would like to do something like StrCmp $1 "6." and have it work. This way I can just see if Net 6 is installed regardless of whether or not its 6.0.8 or 6.0.9 etc... .

Is there a better way to do this other than specifying the full version label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chop off part of the string and compare that:

```
ReadRegStr $2 ...
StrCpy $3 $1 2 ; Copy the first 2 characters
StrCmp $3 "6." "" not6  ; 6.something?
IntCmp $2 0 not6 ; DWORD not 0?
  DetailPrint "Have v$1"
  Goto done
not6:
  Goto loop
```